# Quarkus 3 QR generation using google.zxing native build error

Tags: qr-code, quarkus, zxing, quarkus-native

I am creating a Quarkus 3 application to create a QR code given an url.
In non-native build it works fine, but when packaging it in native mode, it gives me an error about some missing path.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awt in java.library.path at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibraryRelative(NativeLibrarySupport.java:136) at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:50)
```

Here's the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-awt</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the code i am using to generate the QR Code:

```java
public class QRCodeGenerator {

    public static byte[] getQRCodeBytes(String text, int width, int height)
            throws WriterException, IOException {
        String imageFormat = "png"; // could be "gif", "tiff", "jpeg"
        QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.
                encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
        ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream =
                new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, imageFormat, pngOutputStream);
        return pngOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public static String getQRCodeBase64(String text, int width, int height)
            throws WriterException, IOException {
        return encodeBase64String(getQRCodeBytes(text, width, height));
    }

    private static String encodeBase64String(byte[] binaryData) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(binaryData);
    }
}
```

I am asking if anyone has a solution for the error, or another way to handle the QR code generation.
Many thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the dockerfile (i am using Quarkus default native Dockerfile, with a minor modification):

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.8
WORKDIR /work/

COPY ./build_files/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Also here is my Jenkins pipeline config to build this project:

```
mkdir -p /var/xplorer/xplorer-label-dev/build_files
cp target/xplorer-label-*.jar /var/xplorer/xplorer-label-dev/build_files/xplorer-label.jar
cp target/xplorer-label-*-runner /var/xplorer/xplorer-label-dev/build_files/xplorer-label-runner
cp -f Dockerfile /var/xplorer/xplorer-label-dev/Dockerfile
cp -f docker-compose.yml /var/xplorer/xplorer-label-dev/docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: Not directly a solution, but a similar project: https://github.com/turing85/quarkus-qr. Notice that the native build produces/includes `*.so`-files, which must also be copied into the container, see [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/turing85/quarkus-qr/blob/main/src/main/container/Containerfile.native-distroless#L9).

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post and add your `containerfile`? If my suspicion is correct, and the `*.so`-files are missing, then I will formulate an answer.

Comment: @Turing85 hey, i have added more info about the build, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we execute the native build, we see that some `*.so`-Files are also listed as artifacts:

```bash
$ ./mvnw --define native clean verify
...
Produced artifacts:
 /project/libawt.so (jdk_library)
 /project/libawt_headless.so (jdk_library)
 /project/libawt_xawt.so (jdk_library)
 /project/libfontmanager.so (jdk_library)
 /project/libjava.so (jdk_library_shim)
 /project/libjavajpeg.so (jdk_library)
 /project/libjvm.so (jdk_library_shim)
 /project/liblcms.so (jdk_library)
 /project/libmlib_image.so (jdk_library)
...
```

These libraries need to be copied to the container as well:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.8
WORKDIR /work/

COPY ./build_files/*.so /work/
COPY ./build_files/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I have a very similar application [on `github.com`](https://github.com/turing85/quarkus-qr). This is my [corresponding `containerfile` (`github.com`)](https://github.com/turing85/quarkus-qr/blob/main/src/main/container/Containerfile.native-distroless):

```
ARG DISTROLESS_IMAGE="quay.io/quarkus/quarkus-distroless-image:2.0@sha256:142abd361c081de7e4f7922362eb73e3d98f4ca060178688aeb4c969101e853b"

FROM ${DISTROLESS_IMAGE} as runner
ARG APP_DIR=/deployment
ARG UID=1001

USER root
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
COPY \
  --chmod=444 \
  target/*.so /lib/
COPY \
  --chmod=111 \
   target/*-runner ${APP_DIR}/application

ENV LANGUAGE='en_US:en'
USER ${UID}:${UID}
ENTRYPOINT [ "./application" ]
```

Comment: I will try and let you know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yep, that worked! I will edit your answer just to fix a thingh and will accept it.